# Wilcard subdomain based session on multi-tenant laravel application

Tags: php, session, laravel

I am creating a multi-tenant e-commerce application based on laravel. When a user creates a store he will be given a sub-domain. So in order to cater future users of the application I create a wildcard sub-domain.

Each store owner has it's own product/items and etc independent to others. My question is, how can I use session for that particular sub-domain only? Take for example, when a person added a particular item at `mystore.site.com` I want it to be in that store only, so when he browse other store, his cart should be empty unless he went back to `mystore.site.com`.

Is this possible? Because when I open `session` its Session Cookie Path is in the root which I think it will be applied to domain-wide. And I only use 1 laravel installation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two options really.

Firstly, you can hook into the start of the boot process in the application and overwrite the `session.domain` config option at runtime. You'd basically want an early stage process to identify the tenant for the current subdomain and the change the setting like so:

```
Config::set('session.domain', $tenant->domain . '.site.com');
```

Just as further more, you can use the object that gets you the tenant to set the context of requests (easier with the repository pattern).

The second option would be to contain within the session data the actual domain, for example.

```
Session::push('shopping_cart.' . $tenant->domain, $cart);
```

Providing that you use the `push` method on the session, it'll only append things to the specific part of the session, an example being `shopping_cart.mystore` so you could have `shopping_cart.mystore`, `shopping_cart.theirstore` and `shopping_cart.whosstore`. Then you can just create a nice little wrapper for `Session` that will automatically append this allowing you to simple call `Session::get('shopping_cart')`.

You'll notice that above I made the assumption that the domain field contains only the name of the subdomain, minus the actual domain.

Comment: Where should I declare `$tenant->domain` ?

Comment: The assumption is that `$tenant` is an instance of a model representing the current tenant.

Comment: ok, thanks. Maybe I should go for the 2nd option since it gives me more flexibilty to do other things and by just calling `Session::get('shopping_cart' . $tenant->domain);` to get the tenant specific sessions.